# Download AVHRR 1 km SST data

Tags: data, remote-sensing, download, noaa, surface

How to download NOAA AVHRR 1 km resolution sea surface temperature data?

I need a SST 1 km image of the coast of Netherlands with at least 20 % valid pixels.

After searching and searching I find the NEODAAS portal: http://www.neodaas.ac.uk

I find this image: http://www.neodaas.ac.uk/data/browse/file_info.php?image=AVHRR/uk/2017/04/09/09apr170324uksstp.gif

However I cannot figure out how to actually download the image in SST values? Any suggestions? Or maybe a suggestion for another way of acquiring the image?

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to [Dataset Discovery](https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/datasetlist?ids=Measurement&values=Ocean%20Temperature&search=Pathfinder&view=list)

> The 4 km Advanced Very High Resolution Radiometer (AVHRR) Pathfinder Version 5 sea surface temperature (SST) dataset is a reanalysis of historical AVHRR data that have been improved using extensive calibration, validation and other information to yield a consistent research quality time series for global climate studies.

Also, for other dataset you could navigate to [Advanced Very High Resolution Radiometer (AVHRR)](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/AVHRR)

[image]

> The Advanced Very High Resolution Radiometer (AVHRR) provides four- to six-band multispectral data from the NOAA polar-orbiting satellite series. There is fairly continuous global coverage since June 1979, with morning and afternoon acquisitions available. The resolution is 1.1 kilometer at nadir.

For the Vegetation Index: [AVHRR Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI) Composites](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/NDVI)

> Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI) Composites are produced from multiple Advanced Very High Resolution Radiometer (AVHRR) daily observations that have been composited together to create a nearly cloud-free image showing maximum greenness. An NDVI ratio is produced from bands one and two of the AVHRR composite to produce a derived NDVI band composite.

[image]

[image]

For the Land Cover [Global Land Cover Characterization (GLCC)](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/GLCC)

> Global Land Cover Characterization (GLCC) is a series of global land cover classification datasets that are based primarily on the unsupervised classification of 1-km AVHRR (Advanced Very High Resolution Radiometer) 10-day NDVI (Normalized Difference Vegetation Index ) composites. The AVHRR source imagery dates from April 1992 through March 1993. Ancillary data sources included digital elevation data, ecoregions interpretation, and country- or regional-level vegetation and land cover maps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I need the sea surface temperature download, not NDVI or CLCC...

Comment: I've updated my response to a link to the dataset.

Comment: thx, however I only see 4 km resolution.. I see the 1 km resolution being used in a lot of literature, I just can't find it..